# C++ compilation issue error - C2332: <class: missing tag name>

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates, visual-studio-2005

VS 2005 -> Compilation without any errors.

VS 2010 -> Compilation with any errors.

e.g. code snippet

```cpp
template< bool f > struct static_assert;
template<>         struct static_assert<true> { static_assert() {} };
```

Compiler Error:

> error C2332: 'struct': missing tag name

e.g. code snippet

```cpp
template< typename T >
class abcd
{
    struct xyz
    {
        xyz();
        char    c;
        T       tt;
    };
public:
    enum { value = sizeof(xyz)-sizeof(T) < sizeof(T) ? sizeof(xyz)-sizeof(T) : sizeof(T) };
};
```

Compiler Error:

> error C2332: 'class': missing tag name

Any suggestions.

Comment: You need to post the code that instantiates the template.  Otherwise [cannot duplicate](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f581e08bf589324).  Also, why not go right to Visual Studio 2019 instead of using a decade old VS 2010?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie tried the code in VS 2015 but the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first code snippet, the problem is that `static_assert` became a [reserved keyword](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) in the C++11 Standard (VS-2010 seems to be using this), whereas it was an 'allowed' identifier in previous versions of the language (such as the VS-2005 compiler was using). To resolve this issue, change the name of your structure, even if that means simply changing the case of one or two letters:

```cpp
template< bool f > struct Static_Assert; // C++ is case-sensitive, so this is OK!
template<>         struct Static_Assert<true> { Static_Assert() { } };
```

I cannot reproduce the issue in your second code snippet (using VS-2010).

Comment: VS 2010 makes an attempt to use C++ 11.  But it is broken in many aspects when it comes to C++ 11 features, since I guess the engineers were working on the compiler using a draft C++11 standard document.  The earliest version of VS that adheres to the actual C++ 11 standard is VS 2015 with the latest updates applied.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Fair comment. However, the VS-2010 C++ compiler conforms to C++11 sufficiently well to prohibit the use of `static_assert` as an identifier, which is the point of my answer (and the cause of the OP's problem).

Comment: @AdrianMole Thanks for the explanation, got resolved.